# Split pandas df into multiple csvfiles by unique column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a df that I'm trying to split into multiple dfs and then export into csv files.  Basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374995/create-multiple-dataframe-using-for-loop-in-python-2-7), but in Python 3 and with exporting.

My df looks like this (except with ~70 unique locations)

```
Location        Name    Date
OFFICE          Bob     3-Apr-15
OFFICE          Jane    3-Apr-15
HOME            Bob     3-Apr-15
HOME            Jane    4-Apr-15
HOME            John    4-Apr-15
SHOPPING        Suzie   5-Apr-15
SHOPPING        John    5-Apr-15
HOME            Bobby   5-Apr-15
```

and I'd like 3 seperate csv files by location, one for office, one for home, and one for shopping.

I can split the df like this:

```
gbl = globals()
for i in df:
    gbl['df_'+i] = df[df.location==i]
```

but can't print them, and can't figure out how to mass create csv files.

Comment: @ScottBoston Well if they know how to create one, they can create 3. Ami's closure is good, but you can still answer it.

Comment: (The site seemed offline for a few minutes?) @ScottBoston I think it's a duplicate, but, since you think otherwise, reopened it.

Comment: I am out voted here.  Dupe it.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
for n,g in df.groupby('Location'):
    g.to_csv(n+'.csv')
```