# Simplify for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am using python and asking for help on how to simplify the code below. Thanks.

```
for i in range(1,9):
    if i == 1:
        wt_1 = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
    elif i == 2:
        wt_2 = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
    elif i == 3:
        wt_3 = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
    elif i == 4:
        wt_4 = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
    elif i == 5:
        wt_5 = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
    elif i == 6:
        wt_6 = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
    elif i == 7:
        wt_7 = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
    else i == 8:
        wt_8 = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
```

Comment: Let's start with synthax: `gwt_2018.WkNum == i` will be evaluated to either `True` or `False`. Is that your intent? Does `gwt_2018` have a True or False key?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what `gwt_2018` is and what this code is supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
l = [wt_1, wt_2, wt_3, wt_4, wt_5, wt_6, wt_7, wt_8]
for index, i in enumerate(l):
    i = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == index+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that mandatory to have 'wt_i' as variable name for all i's ?

I would use a dictionary instead:

```
wt = {}
for i in range(1,9):
    wt[i] = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did find the solution for my problem.                            gbl = globals()
for i in range(1,54):
    gbl['df_'+str(i)] = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [a link] ([Create multiple dataframe using for loop in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374995/create-multiple-dataframe-using-for-loop-in-python-2-7/35394283))

```
gbl = globals()
for i in range(1,54):
    gbl['df_'+str(i)] = gwt_2018[gwt_2018.WkNum == i]
```